# GitHub Pull Requests in external editor

Tags: github, pull-request

Is there a way to handle GitHub pull requests in an external editor? I hate the web UI and it is very difficult to deal with big pull requests.

Answer (score 0):

What platform are you on? If you're using OS X or Windows, GitHub has an official GUI. Linux has some equivalents.

You can download GitHub for OS X at https://mac.github.com/, or for Windows at https://windows.github.com.

This StackOverflow answer has a list of nice git GUIs for Linux: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516720/git-gui-client-for-linux#1518844

Some text editors even have plugins for PRs! What text editor do you use?

Comment: I'm working on OS X. Notice that i'm not looking for a GitHub client but for a Pull Requests viewer.